# What are the repercussions of changing a ColdFusion-generated WSDL web service from RPC-encoded to document-literal?

Tags: c#, coldfusion, wsdl, visual-studio-2013, coldfusion-9

I inherited a few web services that are WSDLs generated by ColdFusion 9.  The CF9 default is RPC-encoded, so that's what they are.  However, it's recently come to my attention that newer versions of the .NET framework (or maybe it's newer versions of Visual Studio) don't like RPC-encoded WSDLs. In testing (in C#), I verified that VS 2013 only properly consumed the service when it was in the document-literal style.

I'm of course open to changing the style to be more universally usable, but this web service has been in the wild for some time (and is used by a number of people, I'm sure), so I want to ensure I have a handle on what the possible repercussions might be. I'm also wondering if it's possible to get ColdFusion to generate two different WSDLs (or allow setting of the encoding on the fly?). Basically I'd appreciate any advice on the best way to make this compatible (while maintaining backwards compatibility). Thanks.

Comment: Have you read any documentation on it yet? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78a6.html

Comment: Unless I'm missing something from that documentation (which I've read, oh, eight times), that's about how to generate the WSDL, which is not my question. My question is about changing the style of an existing WSDL (and the repercussions of that).

Comment: I was only simply asking and giving you a start since there were no answers yet. Wasn't meant to be an answer or I would've post it as an answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with having a second URL for the document-literal style web service you could just extend your existing CFC. Your new CFC would have all the same functions and logic of the main web service. It would also prevent a There would be no additional code to maintain. The only unknown for me is if this will create any significant additional overhead.

```
<cfcomponent extends="yourExistingCFC" style="document" output="false"></cfcomponent>
```

I did try setting the document type to document-literal on one of my test web services. SoapUI was unable to parse the document-literal WSDL once changed, but Visual Studio could. From this, I would be hesitant on changing the document style of your existing CFC, for you cann't tell how all the client environments will handle the change.

Comment: Ah, clever. I'll try that. And thanks for the testing - the SoapUI issue is exactly the sort of reason I was hesitant to just change the type.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and it appears to generate a valid document-literal WSDL that is consumed properly by Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, though, it throws a `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file` error when actually used. I tested, and receive the same error, in both C# and ColdFusion.  However, if I change the original component to document-literal style and copy the resulting WSDL to a static file, then update the extended component to point to that static file (with the `wsdlfile` attribute) instead of auto-generating one, it works. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: With your static WSDL the binding is still pointing to the existing web service file. As long as the generated soap sent to and from the server looks the same, it doesn't mater were the WSDL comes from. I wasn't able to fully test my suggestion before suggested it. I'm unsure why requests made to an extended service would fail.

Comment: I ended up generating and serving the static WSDLs using a component. It's not ideal, but I'm okay with it as these APIs are updated very infrequently so regenerating a static WSDL each time it's updated isn't much of a maintenance hit (plus I've got limited time to mess with this). I've marked yours as the answer since it set me on the right path. Thanks!